# How to use model instances with ExpressJS, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, express, model

Supposed I have a file 'user.js' which is my user model.
It looks like:

```
var user = function(data) {
    this.data = data;
}
user.getUserByID = function(data, callback) {
    db.get(...., function(data) {
        callback(new user(data));
    });
}
user.prototype.save = function(data, callback) {
    this.data = data;
    db.save(...., function(result) {
        callback(result);
    });
}
module.exports = user;
```

And now my router has two routes:

```
app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
    user.getUserByID(req.user.id, function(user) {
        res.someAction(user);
    });
});
app.post('/updateProfile', function(req, res) {
    user.getUserByID(req.user.id, function(user) {
        user.save(req.body.data);
        res.someAction(user);
    });
});
```

Now, here, I have to get the user instance again when I have to save it, which I don't really like. I would ideally like the user to be available all the time.
Also, what happens to the old user object? Is it possible to persist it somehow?

What is a good way to organize my model code? I am using mysql db and node-mysql package.

Comment: Do you want the user object from the GET /profile request to persist to the POST /updateProfile request?

Comment: Yup. Though, if there are better ways than that to build my model, i am open to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the user objects inside a map, that has user id as the key and  user object as the value.

```
var userMap = {}
app.post('/updateProfile', function(req, res) {
    if userMap[req.user.id] === undefined){
    user.getUserByID(req.user.id, function(user) {
        user.save(req.body.data);
        userMap[req.user.id] = req.body.data
        res.someAction(userMap[req.user.id]);
    });
  }else{
    userMap[req.user.id].save(req.body.data);        
    userMap[req.user.id] = req.body.data
    res.someAction(user);
  }
})
```